# Unit testing: how much do I need to mock?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am currently beginning to start unit testing and I don't know what to mock and what not. What I understood is that the class I want to test should be completely isolated, so it only deals with mocks.

For example, if I have a class which has a method in it it calls `getAnyobject()`. Then it calls its `anyObject.getId()` method and stores it. In my unit test I write a method `build()`, where I create an instance of `AnyObject`, `anyObj`. Then I set an ID, with `setId(01)`.

After building everything I write a test method. There I write: `doReturn(anyObj).when(classUnderTest.theServiceIuse.getAnyObject())`. I do that, because my test would fail, if the `serviceIuse.getAnyObject()` wouldn't work correctly. In addition to that I would also have to mock the `getID()` method from the `AnyObject` class. Since I don't want to test the `AnyObject` class.

Is this really true that I need to mock so much, or is it unnecessary for me to even call the `setID()` method?

Comment: Can you add the code you want to test? I think you are trying to test a getter method but something doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep this in mind. If code was written to be easy to test, mocking wouldn't be necessary. You could, for example, just override the methods with empty implementations.

That is why you almost never need to mock POJOs; you can just as easily create an instance and use that. You need mocks when the code calls methods which "do too much" (like talking to a database) or which have too many dependencies.

A typical case is testing service `Foo`. In the real code, `Foo` needs other services to do its work. For the test, you just want to make sure `Foo` uses the other services correctly (i.e. check the API is adhered to); you don't actually want the other services do anything. The problem is that you can't easily disable services from a test (like telling Java "don't do anything when method `formatHarddrive()` is called).

The workaround is to create a mock for the service which you then inject into `Foo` in some way. The mock just exposes the smallest possible amount of API.

Another reason for mocking is testing error handling. For this, you want exceptions at certain points in the code. Mocking frameworks come with comfortable ways to achieve this.

Comment: The thing is, that currently I am writing tests for classes, which already exists, just to try it out. But the thing is, that I ask myself, that when I don't have a class, where I see what happens in the methods, I do need to know which other methods the class could call.

Comment: To write a test, you need to know what your code s doing. There is a method called black box testing but that's mostly relevant for security (where you bombard the code with all kind of inputs to see whether it breaks). For unit tests, you have to have the source code.

Comment: But the principle of Test Driven Development is,  as far as  I know, that you write the tests before you write the actual code. So yes I do know, what my Code should do in the end, but how this is accomplished I don't and with that which methods of which class...

Comment: TDD works with new code, not with existing one. For existing code, you write tests (as good as you can), then you refactor and simplify code+tests (to make sure the new code still behaves as before).

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time. I will write lower level class code first instead of mocking. I will use mock when the module is not developing in this package or rely on other service code.